# verification of Sup X <= Inf Y

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

I have proven this question but somehow I feel like maybe I have done something wrong or I have been reckless somewhere would you please help me to verify my answer

If S is a set with least upper bound and greatest lower bound property assume X and Y are nonempty subset of S such that every element of X <= every element of Y so prove Sup X <= Inf Y

I have proven this in the following way

from the hypotheses we can conclude everything in Y is an upper bound of X and vice versa.

so Sup X and Inf Y exists in s and lets denote them by a and b now lets prove this by contradiction lets suppose a>b since b is infimum of Y everything greater than b is not lower bound and this is in contradiction of a not being a lower bound of Y because  a  is supremum of X
and since everything in Y is an upper bound of X . is my proof true or I am missing something in somewhere?

Comment: Another question about the same inequality: [Prove that $\sup S \leq \inf T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3508153). If you're interested mainly in feedback to your proof, you should use the ([tag:solution-verification]) tag, see also the [corresponding tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\sup S \leq \inf T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3508153/prove-that-sup-s-leq-inf-t)